# I need to know how to search to display results according to two or more criteria

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, char, c++14

I'm making a program to help me with my DJ sets. I want to be able to input either a song name or a song key have results displayed.

As you can see, I've done a few If-statements based on the keys. My problem is, I want to be able to search by song name, not just key.

So, if I enter Learn to Fly, I want all songs in the key of D to appear; if I enter D, I want the same.

How can I associate a song with a key and a key with a song?

Please be as detailed as you want. I've only taken one programming class, and it was 2 years ago.

> #include 
>       #include
>
> ```
> using namespace std;
>
> int main()
> {
>   string input;
>   while (cin >> input)
>   {
>       char const *x[] = { "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "D#m", "Eb", "E", "F" ;}
>       cout << "Enter a key or song name: ";
>       cin >> input;
>       if (input == "D")
>       {
>           cout << "Songs harmonic to D, includes G, A, Bm: " << endl <<
>               "Learn to Fly, Inpetto (D) " << endl <<
>               "Stranger, Chris Lake (D) " << endl <<
>               "Boneless (A)" << endl;
>
>           ;
>       }
>       if (input == "Fm")
>       {
>           cout << "Songs harmonic to Fm, includes Bbm/A#m, Cm, Dm, Bb/A#: " << endl << endl <<
>               "Five Hours (Fm)" << endl <<
>               "Cannonball, Showtek (Fm)" << endl <<
>               "Devil's Den (Fm)" << endl <<
>               "Virus, Martin Garrix (Fm)" << endl <<
>               "Get Loose (Fm)" << endl <<
>               "Fight Club, Eric Mendoza  (Fm)" << endl <<
>               "Go, Firebeatz (Fm)" << endl <<
>               "We Make it Bounce (A#) " << endl <<
>               "Saksata (Bbm)" << endl <<
>               "FKN INSANE (Cm)" << endl <<
>               "One, SHM (Dm)" << endl <<
>               "Boy Oh Boy (Cm/110 BPM)" << endl <<
>               "Drop It (C) " << endl;
>
>
>       }
>
>       if (cin >> "Ebm" >> "D#m")
>       {
>           cout << "Boneless (C#m)" << endl <<
>               "Roar, Axwell (Ebm)" << endl <<
>               "Madness, Dimitri Vegas (Abm) " << endl <<
>               "Ravefield, Thomas Newman  (Abm) " << endl <<
>               "Shipwreck (G#m)" << endl;
>
>       } // Problem here also. I want to say "If user inputs either Ebm or D#m, display the same result.
>   }
>
>
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: I'd recommend using a database of some sort here, that's a much better tool for the job than a hard-coded string list. With a SQLite database you could (for example) do a `SELECT * FROM Songs WHERE Name LIKE "(input)" OR Key LIKE "(input)"`.

Comment: Do you know which one I download? I use Windows 8.1.  Here's the list of options: https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: How big is the song collection expected to be??